# Indexed field wont help: How to improve query time

Tags: sql, sql-server

The first/uncached query takes a long time if I check the [deliverybody] field contains 'x' or not, to eliminate the rows with 'x'. [deliverytime] is indexed and query completed in a second if I don't check for 'x'.

With *AND [deliverybody] <> 'x'* part the query execution time is 10+ seconds, without; 1 second. It seems like indexed field [deliverytime] won't help too much.

Query only returns 1600 rows. Scanning extra 1600 fields takes 10+ seconds. What's wrong with the query?

**UPDATE:** Upgraded from NTEXT to NVARCHAR(MAX). Execution plans of inner query:

- SLOW Execution plan as saved: http://pastebin.com/7X7uf6iV

This query takes 10+ seconds:

```
  SELECT MAX([deliveryid]) AS deliveryid, COUNT(*) AS cnt  
  FROM [_hMaiServer].[dbo].[hm_deliverylog]
  WHERE [deliverytime] > DATEADD(HOUR, -24, GETDATE()) 
  AND [deliverybody] <> 'x' 
  GROUP BY deliverysubject
```

- FAST Execution plan as saved: http://pastebin.com/EEnPGf4X

The query completed in a second:

```
SELECT MAX([deliveryid]) AS deliveryid, COUNT(*) AS cnt  
FROM [_hMaiServer].[dbo].[hm_deliverylog]
WHERE [deliverytime] > DATEADD(HOUR, -2400, GETDATE()) 
--AND [deliverybody] <> 'x' 
GROUP BY deliverysubject
```

And the table structure with the indexes:  http://pastebin.com/W0PsDnqS

**My conclusion:**

Checking 5000 rows takes 10+ seconds.  Smaller **{HOUR}** value makes the execution time quicker. If this is OK here is no problem but it seems slow to me.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [hm_deliverylog]
WHERE [deliverybody] <> 'x' 
AND [deliverytime] > DATEADD(HOUR, -__{HOUR}__ , GETDATE())
```

Comment: List all indexes and their columns on the table `hm_deliverylog`

Comment: What is the output of `SET STATISTICS IO ON;` then running each query? And execution plans?

Comment: [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx): *Important
ntext, text, and image data types **will be removed** in a future version of SQL Server. **Avoid using these data types** in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.*

Comment: BTW your `LIKE` doesn't contain any wildcards so you are checking for `is x` not `contains x` if that is your actual code.

Comment: @Martin: I can't check WHERE [deliverybody] <> 'x' because it's NTEXT...

Comment: Why are you using the deprecated NTEXT type? It's NVARCHAR(MAX) replacement supports all string operations, including `<>`.

Comment: I've upgraded to NVARCHAR(MAX).

Comment: You seems to have fondness of giving out *pictures* of the required information, rather than the actual information. Post **the execution plan** (right click, save as .sqlplan file), not a picture of it. Post **the actual index definition** (right click, extract script), not an image of it. As the old saying goes: in troubleshooting a line of text is worth a thousand bitmaps...

Comment: Is the 'x' fixed, or subject to user input. If fixed you could add a computed column that indicates whether the deliverybody is 'x' or not

Comment: I wonder if you could use windowing functions instead of a nested subquery to generate your aggregates over related rows.  I would personally try this to see if performance is difference.  Not saying I have alot of confidence that performance would be better, but it would probably be different(hopefully in the direction of faster).

Comment: I modified the question & query and made them simpler to solve the problem.

Comment: `SET STATISTICS IO ON;` results? The only difference in the plans is that the slower one brings out 4138 LOB columns to the filter but as the max length of a LOB is 2GB that could be anything up to 8TB  of data!

Comment: Also what version are you on? The tests in my answer are on 2012 but I've just tested on 2008 R2 and the results are different. The rewrite and the original both perform the same without loads of unnecessary reads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided the requested `SET STATISTICS IO ON;` results.

One possible improvement however might be instead of using

```
WHERE [deliverybody] <> 'x'
```

to use

```
WHERE NOT (LEN([deliverybody]) = 1 AND LEFT([deliverybody],1) = 'X')
```

An example where this is beneficial below.

```
CREATE TABLE T1
  (
     Id             INT,
     [deliverybody] VARCHAR(MAX)
  )

INSERT INTO T1
VALUES     (1, Replicate(Cast('A' AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 2000000000)),
           (2,'X')

SET STATISTICS IO ON;

SELECT id
FROM   T1
WHERE  NOT ( Len([deliverybody]) = 1
             AND LEFT([deliverybody], 1) = 'X' )

SELECT id
FROM   T1
WHERE  [deliverybody] <> 'X'

DROP TABLE T1
```

The IO results for both are below

```
Table 'T1'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0
            , lob logical reads 6, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

---

```
Table 'T1'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0
    lob logical reads 2209665, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 642255.
```

The first one has significantly fewer reads as it avoids dragging out the whole 2GB value in order to discover that it is not `X`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/EX17K0GZ Checking the length increased the time a bit. I think I'll give up and won't check for 'x', I got only 5K rows but it takes a long time... Or I'll filter TOP 100 rows and it will be nearly 100 rows because of filtered 'x' fields.

Comment: @NimeCloud - Actually those IO stats don't look too bad. An average of 6 LOB reads per column. Laurence's suggestion of creating a persisted computed column with definition `CASE WHEN deliverybody = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` seems a good one to me then refer to that in your query.

Comment: I simply cropped AND [deliverybody] <> 'x' part from this subquery and will use at master query if really necessary. Comparing NVARCHAR(MAX) takes a while and I can't index it, that's what I've learned. In code, adding another column which one indicates the body is 'x' or not is much better and faster to query. Thanks for the help, much appreciated.